# Guideline for Inter Service Communication with principal propagation with Cloud SDK on CF

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

We are trying to set two micro services where the principal needs to be propagated from the first microservice(Login happens here) to the second one (This uses cloud SDK to talk to S/4 Hana Cloud). Has this particular scenario been explored before / is there any existing guideline the Cloud SDK team suggests.

Comment: Hi Anirban, what version of the Cloud SDK do you use at the moment? Have you tried anything yet or just starting with your services? It also looks like your problem is better solved with Single Sign On (SSO) and not principal propagation as the latter is dedicated to connecting Cloud with On-Premise. Please add more details so that we can figure out some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Anirban

The Cloud SDK capabilities related to Principal propagation in conjunction with OAuth flow are nicely explained in this [blog article by Marco Dahms](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/02/05/deep-dive-8-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-leverage-principal-propagation-via-oauth-2-when-consuming-a-business-api-from-s4hana-cloud/). 
I hope you'll find an idea of how to adapt it to your use case. There are additional helpful links in the comments section of the blog.

If you give more details or what solutions you have already tried we are happy to help you further.

Cheers,
Artem